# Is it bad practice to use Action and Func all the time instead of making corresponding delegates?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action, func

A lot of time when creating simple events in my program that other classes can subscribe to instead of making a delegate and creating an event from the delegate I just create the event with either Action or Func to avoid having to create the delegate.

Is there any downsides to doing this?

Comment: Is it still readable? That's your motivation one way or another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really, the only downside I can think of is that if you have a logical intention (beyond the parameters and return values expected) that you want the user to satisfy that may get lost using the generic delegates.

For example:

```
   public delegate void ClearAllValuesDelegate(MyClass X);

   // ...

   ClearAllValuesDelegate myDelegate;
```

vs:

```
   Action<MyClass> myDelegate;
```

In the former, it's clear the intention is that the action should clear all the values in the reference (though there's no way to enforce this of course).  Whereas `Action<>` just tells you what it takes and not much else.  Like I said, this is just a logical difference.

But really there's no big downside that I'm aware of.  Most of the time when we use `Func<>` and `Action<>` we are simply asking the caller to give us a target that satisfies the inputs/outputs only.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference to me is the difference between:

[image]

And:

[image]

Obviously, there is at least *some* value in having the parameter named.

Answer (score 1):

imho it's a matter of preference, to the CLR it's the same thing